# How to indent multiple lines starting at the same column?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

How can I select the block of lines within the red box and indent them? I want to indent from `name:` onward only.

[image]

Comment: select those lines. Press TAB to move forward. Press Shift+TAB to move backward

Comment: But how can it be select without select the beginning of the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> to enable highlighting by column, select the lines you wish to indent, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or whatever else you want to do) to:

[image: column highlighting]

This is also handy for bulk editing multiple columns at a time.  Note that a formatter extension *may* format this and remove the extra indents, so you might need to configure that.

Comment: I use google translate   
I am a new member to this community   
I'm glad I got the first answer  
Does giving thanks go against the site's policy?
thank you all

Comment: @RAFIK-KZ technically comments aren't meant to be used for giving thanks, but it's not a big deal.  Welcome.

Comment: How can I create  [an animation like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdB9g.gif) the one you showed in the explanation?

Comment: @RAFIK-KZ I use a tool called [Screen to GIF](https://www.screentogif.com/) to record my screen, then upload the .gif file as you would a screenshot on the site.  The site supports animated gifs in posts.

Comment: Timothy G. thank you I want an animation that explains how to insert an image and it appears on the face of the page
Not the same as the link I included